# Conditional distinctUntilChanged in angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a filter class that I inherit wherever I want filter functionality.

```
export class FilterUtil{
…
  public extFilterSubject = new Subject<any>();
  constructor(){
    this.extFilterSubject
      .pipe(map(event => event)
        , debounceTime(300)
        , distinctUntilChanged())
      .subscribe((searchKeyword) => {
         //filter logic here.
      })
   }
}
```

This works.

The thing I want to accomplish is to apply distinctUntilUnchanged conditionally.
I have come across one of the cases where I don't want distinctUntilUnchanged operator.

I looked into the [official docs for distinctUntilUnchanged](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinctUntilChanged). But I couldnot find anything relevant.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: You want to conditionally apply `distinctUntilChanged` only to some emissions or conditionally to some chains created by this class?

Comment: @martin I want to conditionally apply distinctUntilChanged only to some emissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can only compare current value with the last value emitted.
If you would want to apply your own condition.

```
distinctUntilChanged((valueOne: any, valueTwo: any) => {
            if (Your Condition) {
                return true; // This means values are equal, it will not emit the current value
            } else {
                return false;// This means the values are different, so it will emit
            }
        })
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Had to emit the values using flatMap operator to make it work.